# String manipulation, optional character

Tags: bash

With `grep`, you can use a question mark `?` to signify an optional character, that is a character that is to be matches 0 or 1 times.

```
$ foo=qwerasdf

$ grep -Eo fx? <<< $foo
f
```

The question is does Bash String Manipulation have a similar feature? Something like

```
$ echo ${foo%fx?}
```

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You're probably talking about [parameter expansion](http://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bashref.html#Shell-Parameter-Expansion). It uses shell patterns, not regular expression, so <strike>the answer is no</strike>.

Upon further reading, I noticed that if you

```
shopt -s extglob
```

you can use [extended pattern matching](http://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bashref.html#Pattern-Matching) which can achieve something similar to regex, albeit with slightly different syntax.

Check this out:

```
word="mre"
# this returns true
if [[ $word == m?(o)re ]]; then echo true; else echo false; fi

word="more"
# this also returns true
if [[ $word == m?(o)re ]]; then echo true; else echo false; fi

word="mooooooooooore"
# again, true
if [[ $word == m+(o)re ]]; then echo true; else echo false; fi
```

Works with parameter expansion too,

```
word="noooooooooooo"
# outputs 'nay'
echo ${word/+(o)/ay}
# outputs 'nayooooooooooo'
echo ${word/o/ay}
```